# Can my UPDATE statements will work if run concurrently in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, concurrentmodification

I saw many similar questions but still I am not fully sure if I am correct.

We have an application which launches a job to mass send many messages. The messages delivery status are received later in batches and in no particular order.

The table structure is like:-

```
CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `pk` char(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `job_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  KEY `job_id` (`job_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The records are initially created with `status` set to null. Its value is expected to change from null to `sent` and then to `delivered`. Below statements are used to update the records.

When status to be set is - `delivered`

```
Update message SET status = 'delivered', update_date = Now()
    WHERE job_id = :someId
```

When status to be set is - `sent`

```
Update message SET status = 'sent', update_date = Now()
    WHERE job_id = :someId AND status IS NULL
```

Problem is, that it is possible that there could be two threads concurrently trying to set the `status` of same record to 'sent' and 'delivered'. In this case 'delivered' is the final status so we would want that to win eventually.

Will the above statements ensure this in MySql or MariaDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in both MySQL and MariaDB (and probably any SQL database).
updates to the same row are atomic.

- 'sent' will overwrite NULL, but not 'delivered'
- 'delivered' will overwrite NULL and 'sent'

This is what you want. Just make sure message with given job_id exists before updating it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Update message SET status = 'delivered', update_date = Now()
    WHERE job_id = :someId
      AND status = 'sent'    -- add this??
```

(There should be no difference between MySQL and MariaDB in this area.)

Comment: It is possible that the 'delivered' status was delivered before the 'sent' status. In that case we would want to record the 'delivered' status and ignore the 'sent' one. Anyway what I was trying to arrive at is there a chance that the 'delivered' update is about to update the record at that very instance if 'sent's update too runs and 'sees' that the `status` is still null. In the meantime the `status` gets updated to 'delivered' but then the 'sent' update 'saw' null so it eventually sets it to 'sent'. But I guess relational database being guaranteeing atomicity, this won't happen.

Comment: @AppleGrew - What is the value of `autocommit`?  Is the `UPDATE` in a `BEGIN...COMMIT` transactions?  If each `UPDATE` is a transaction unto itself, then your original pair of `UPDATEs` was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Update message SET status = 'sent', update_date = Now()
WHERE job_id = :someId
AND status != 'delivered';
```